# Verificar se existe determinado item dentro de array, através de uma variável

Tags: javascript, array, react

Digamos que eu tenha esse array:

```
let checkOne = [
{
"id": 273,
"attributes": {
"humidity": {
"qty": 74.3223333333333,
"unit": "percents"
},
"protein": {
"qty": 23.525,
"unit": "g"
},
"lipid": {
"qty": 1.23766666666667,
"unit": "g"
},
}
}];
```

Quero atráves da variável ***tipo*** verificar se o conteúdo que está na mesma existe dentro do array:

```
//Tentava
let tipo = 'protein'
let resultado = (typeof checkOne[0].attributes.tipo !== 'undefined');

console.log(resultado) //era para retornar true, mas aparece false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na forma de acessar os atributos de um objeto. Considere este exemplo simples:

```js
let pessoa = {
    idade: 20
};

console.log(pessoa.idade); // 20
console.log(pessoa['idade']); // 20
```

O objeto `pessoa` possui um atributo chamado "idade". E para acessá-lo, você pode usar `pessoa.idade` ou `pessoa["idade"]` - na primeira você acessa o atributo diretamente, na segunda, como uma string contendo o nome da propriedade entre colchetes.

Agora, se o nome da propriedade está em uma variável, a primeira forma não funciona (somente a segunda):

```js
let pessoa = {
    idade: 20
};

let nomePropriedade = 'idade';
console.log(pessoa.nomePropriedade); // undefined
console.log(pessoa[nomePropriedade]); // 20
```

Isso porque `pessoa.nomePropriedade` é o mesmo que `pessoa["nomePropriedade"]`, ou seja, estou procurando por uma propriedade cujo nome é "nomePropriedade". Somente usando  `pessoa[nomePropriedade]` eu consigo obter a propriedade cujo nome é o valor da variável `nomePropriedade`.

---

Sendo assim, no seu caso `attributes.tipo` está buscando por uma propriedade chamada "tipo" e não vai funcionar. Então você precisaria usar a segunda opção (a variável entre colchetes, ou seja, `attributes[tipo]`):

```js
let checkOne = [{
        "id": 273,
        "attributes": {
            "humidity": {
                "qty": 74.3223333333333,
                "unit": "percents"
            },
            "protein": {
                "qty": 23.525,
                "unit": "g"
            },
            "lipid": {
                "qty": 1.23766666666667,
                "unit": "g"
            },
        }
    }
];

let tipo = 'protein';
let resultado = (typeof checkOne[0].attributes[tipo] !== 'undefined');

console.log(resultado); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Se você tentar acessar o atributo desta maneira `checkOne[0].attributes.tipo`, você está tentando acessar a variável tipo dentro dos atributos, e sempre dará falso.

Se precisa acessar um atributo de um objeto de forma dinâmica, você precisa acessá-lo com colchetes:

```
let tipo = 'protein';
checkOne[0].attributes[tipo] // js vai interpretar como checkOne[0].attributes.protein
```

Então você pode utilizar isso para criar uma função e verificar se o item possui o atributo.

```
function possuiTipo(item, tipo) {
    return item.attributes[tipo] !== undefined; // se existir retornará true;
}
```

*Se quiser saber quais são todos os itens que possui esse tipo, você pode utilizar a função [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) juntamente com a função anterior.*

```
const tipo = "protein";
const resultado = checkOne.filter(item => {
    return possuiTipo(item, tipo)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa condição `typeof checkOne[0].attributes.tipo !== 'undefined'` será sempre `false`, pois não existe uma propriedade `tipo` dentro de `attributes`, ou seja, `attributes.tipo` é `undefined`.

Além disso você pode checar diretamente a propriedade `protein` usando a função `some`:

```js
checkOne.some(item=>item.attributes.protein) // return true se ao menos um elemento possui attributes.protein
```

Comment: mas no meu caso eu preciso verificar mais de uma propriedade.

Comment: digamos que preciso verificar 100 propriedades, se for por essa lógica teria que escrever checkOne.some(item=>item.attributes.propX) 100 vezes